# IIS profiling with .net profiler

Tags: .net, iis

Am i able to attach normal .net profiler (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/profiling-overview) to IIS application?

Comment: In general, any good enough .NET profiler can attach to an ASP.NET application on IIS. But, you do need the vendor of that profiler to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use any .net profiler with the IIS .net application. You just need to select the option in profilers like profile iis application or iis-asp.net.sometime you need to enter some information like URL and port etc.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that I need to create my own .net profiler which I don't know how attach to iis server.